# How do I omit certain parts of a string with python's re?

Tags: python, python-re

I have this string:

```
url = '/justicefor/404/1nirmala5.jpg'
```

I want to extract it as `404.jpg`.
I tried something like:

```py
pattern = re.compile(
         r"./justicefor/(\d+/.\.\w+)",
         re.IGNORECASE
    )
```

But this selects the text between **404** and **jpg** too. How do I fix this?

I'm new to regular expressions so

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution,

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/m8axZl/1)

```
import re

re.sub("/justicefor/(.*)/.*(\.\w+)", r"\1\2", "/justicefor/404/1nirmala5.jpg")
```

---

```
'404.jpg'
```

Comment: I am using `findall(url)`. So I want 404 and jpg to be in a single string with find_all. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes you can try, ``[i + j for i, j in re.findall("<regex>", "<input_str>")]``

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os` module

**Ex:**

```
import os

url = '/justicefor/404/1nirmala5.jpg'

path, ext = os.path.splitext(url)
print(os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path)) + ext)  #--> 404.jpg
```